# sort by model attribute in controller in user show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, controller

I have a book review/discussion site and would like to order all the users books on their profile page based on wether they are currently reading that book. I added a column to the book model called current and when users add a book they can check a box that says "I'm currently reading this." If the user clicks the box then the book object has a :current attribute with a value of "1". If they don't click the box then the value of :current is "0".

In my view I have this code to tell the user which books they are currently reading, and it works fine.

```
      <% if book.current == "1" %>
        <h4>I am currently reading this book</h4>
      <% end %>
```

However in my show user controller I can't make it order the incomiing objects by the :current status.

Here's what I've tried:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @books= Book.all.sort { |p1, p2| p1.current <=> p2.current }
end
```

and

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @books = Book.all
  @books = @books.order(:current)
end
```

and

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @books = Book.all
  @books = @books.order(current: :desc)
end
```

and, just to make sure it was going the right way

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @books = Book.all
  @books = @books.order(current: :asc)
end
```

None work. And, none throw errors, they just don't sort it. The "current" book that is last instead of first. Here's the code that displays and loops out the users books. This code also works fine.

```
<% @user.books.each do |book| %>
  <% if params[:id].to_s == book.user_id.to_s %>
    <ul class="profileDisplay" >

      <img alt="Book Jacket" class="homepageImages" src=<%= book.image %> >
      <% if book.current == "1" %>
        <h4>I am currently reading this book</h4>
      <% end %>
      <p><b>Contributor: </b><%= book.user.name %></p>
      <p><b>Title: </b><%= book.title %></p>
      <p><b>Author: </b><%= book.author %></p>
      <p><b>Genre: </b><%= book.genre %></p>
      <p><b>Publication Date: </b><%= book.publication_date %></p>
      <p><b>Publisher: </b><%= book.publisher %></p>
      <p><b>Synopsis: </b><%= book.synopsis %></p>
      <% if params[:id] == session[:user_id].to_s || params[:action] == "profile" %>
        <%= button_to "Edit Book", book_edit_path(book.id), method: "get", class: "btn btn-primary col-xs-2" %>
        <%= button_to "Delete Book", delete_book_path(book.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this book and all it's reviews?"}, class: "btn btn-danger col-xs-2" %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On view, `@user.books` are not sorted yet.

You sorted them and assigned it into `@books`

I think it should be like this

**CONTROLLER**

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @books = @user.books.order(current: :desc)
end
```

**VIEW**

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <!-- show book records here -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: worked! thanks, and with it this way I can take the user check out of the view, which I tried to implement when I made it in the first place but couldn't figure it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

add default scope in book model

```
default_scope  { order(:current=> :desc) }
```

and your controller

```
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

and views

```
<% @user.books.each do |book| %>
  #do whatever
<% end %>
```